# execute a script without reading permissions on alpine image

Tags: file-permissions, alpine-linux

I have a script that I want to execute but I don't want the user to see it,
I have tried with shc (with multi-stage build) but then i can't execute it on alpine ("cannot execute binary file")
alpine doesn't have shc package that why i did multi-stage with ubuntu in STAGE1

any idea on how to execute a file without reading permissons?

tried:
`apk add libc6-compat`
it didnt worked

```
file script.sh 
script.sh: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=b51293b8b652f24e1e8693c2ceba82108d6435b2, stripped
```